# OnAppearing is called every time Xamarin.Android rejects the permission request dialog

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, permissions

When creating an app with Xamarin.Android

OnAppearing is called every time I reject the permission request dialog.

Is the Android permission request dialog modal?

Comment: Can you please show the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a known issue [OnAppearing called after permission dialog on Android](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/10051) .

If `MainPage` is not inside `NavigationPage` the problem does not exists.